# Uninstall option not showing for installed apps in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-desktop

I installed app from store when i want to uninstall the app, when right click of app it showing only two options it showing like as below image, how to show uninstall when right click on app..

[image]

Comment: Usually this means the app is already uninstalled. It's just not reflecting so a normal log out and log in back will fix this or you probably need to restart your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried w10_pin_to-start.reg tool from online search and restarted my pc the problem is fixed for me...